# Is the state of the ethereum blockchain changed with each transaction or with each block?

Tags: transactions, mining, blocks

Assume we have two transactions A and B which are put into a block by a miner (first A then B). Will both transactions be executed with the state of the previous block or will transaction B be executed with the state resulting from the execution of A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ethereum is single-threaded. Any opcode in any contract is executed **sequentially**. The answer to your question is that transaction B is executed with the state as per the changes applied by transaction A.

The reason the EVM (v1) has been architected this way is that otherwise concurrent state-updates would result in non-deterministic behavior. You need sharding to fix that, and that is coming in Ethereum 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

Transaction B be executed with the state resulting from the execution of A.